# Ruby : How to launch a java server from inside a ruby script

Tags: java, ruby

how do I have to modify the following ruby script to make it work? (I'm on Linux.)

```
# 1. Launch a java server:
system "java -jar myJavaServer.jar -someArgument -otherArgument"

# 2. Execute some ruby code (with the server running):
[...]

# 3. Stop the java server:
system "killall java"
```

I suppose the java server must be launched into a separate ruby thread so the following code gets executed with the server running...?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fork() to run the java server in one process and your ruby code in the other.

```
pid = fork()
if pid then
    # This is the parent process. Execute your ruby code here
    # then kill the process running the java server
    system "kill #{pid}"
else
    # this is the child process, run the java server here
    system "java -jar myJavaServer.jar -someArgument -otherArgument"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this seems to prevent the server from being launched. (I get an error message with the ampersand...)

Comment: Hmm. Okay, how about this. Write a shell script that launches the java server in the background (with the &), executes your ruby script, and then does "killall java".

Comment: I haven't mentioned it, but it's actually a Rails app that is supposed to execute the ruby script... So I'd prefer to do it all from inside this ruby script - if somebody has that solution...

Comment: In that case, do a fork() inside your ruby script right before you launch the java server. I'll edit my answer to explain how.

Comment: Thanks - that works almost always. What I had to do to make it work every time: add 'sleep 15' right after the 'if', because the code in the 'if' clause needs the server to be up already. If you have a more elegant solution (than 'sleep...') for this condition, I would of course be all ears!